# Apply a function that uses multiple rows and multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, haversine

I have a df which can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kYJVhsLQIDMe0s7QpuTDRr0K4teVU-9U88RIp2Ouk6g/edit?usp=sharing).

I am trying to calculate haversine distance between every row of 'lat_long' feature against every column after the 'lat_long' column. There are total 45 rows and 45 columns to work on.

This is my formula:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r
```

When I called it using a for loop:

```
for i, j in zip(data['lat_long'], data.columns[8:]):
    x, y = i.split(',')
    a, b = j.split(',')
    x = float(x)
    y = float(y)
    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    data[i] = data.apply(lambda coordinates: haversine(coordinates[x], coordinates[y], coordinates[a], coordinates[b]), axis=1)
```

This supposed to fill all the values in all the columns with the distance between those two points but I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-aa9c17327bac> in <module>
      6     a = float(a)
      7     b = float(b)
----> 8     data[i] = data.apply(lambda data: haversine(data[x], data[y], data[a], data[b]), axis=1)
      9 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6904             kwds=kwds,
   6905         )
-> 6906         return op.get_result()
   6907 
   6908     def applymap(self, func):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185 
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187 
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    290 
    291         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 292         self.apply_series_generator()
    293 
    294         # wrap results

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    319             try:
    320                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 321                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    322                     keys.append(v.name)
    323             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-84-aa9c17327bac> in <lambda>(data)
      6     a = float(a)
      7     b = float(b)
----> 8     data[i] = data.apply(lambda data: haversine(data[x], data[y], data[a], data[b]), axis=1)
      9 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1062         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   1063         try:
-> 1064             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1065 
   1066             if not is_scalar(result):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4719         k = com.values_from_object(key)
   4720 
-> 4721         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4722         try:
   4723             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _convert_scalar_indexer(self, key, kind)
   3111             if kind in ["getitem", "ix"] and is_float(key):
   3112                 if not self.is_floating():
-> 3113                     return self._invalid_indexer("label", key)
   3114 
   3115             elif kind in ["loc"] and is_float(key):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _invalid_indexer(self, form, key)
   3331             "cannot do {form} indexing on {klass} with these "
   3332             "indexers [{key}] of {kind}".format(
-> 3333                 form=form, klass=type(self), key=key, kind=type(key)
   3334             )
   3335         )

TypeError: ("cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [13.721345] of <class 'float'>", 'occurred at index 0')
```

What went wrong?

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Would you please a sample of the data? It would help to help you. Not a screenshot.

Comment: Can you insert above data[i] = data.apply... print (a, b, x, y) and show us the output.

Comment: I have shared the dataframe link above now. Its on googe sheets. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: When I print, a,b,x,y I get the values I need.